# CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing. in Django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, csrf-token

I am really confused because I can't avoid this error. My previous projects were not engaged with this error. So anyways I hope you can find solution.

here is my settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-n^s54jl394v4!_#n^78&7o-9swqt*ckq1pcyx_g3@vhb$8gct5'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "rest_framework",
    "accounts",
    "contents",
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication"
    ]
}
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join("static")
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

and here is my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls")),
    path("contents/", include("contents.urls")),
]
```

here is accounts.views:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate

from accounts.serializers import UserCreationSerializer, UserLoginSerializer


class RegisterAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    model = User
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserCreationSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        username = serializer.validated_data.get("username")
        password = serializer.validated_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return Response(
                data={"msg": "User created successfully and logged in"},
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        return Response(
            data={"msg": "User Creation process failed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()


class UserLoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.user.is_authenticated)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            username = serializer.validated_data['username']
            password = serializer.validated_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return Response({'message': 'User logged in successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({'message': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class LogoutAPIView(APIView):
    model = User

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
        return Response(data={"msg": "User logged out successfully!"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

accounts.urls

```
from django.urls import path
from accounts import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("register/", views.RegisterAPIView.as_view(), name="register"),
    path("login/", views.UserLoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path("logout/", views.LogoutAPIView.as_view(), name="logout")
]
```

accounts.serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


class UserCreationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ["username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "password"]
        model = User

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        user = self.Meta.model
        return user.objects.create_user(
            username=self.validated_data.get("username"),
            email=self.validated_data.get("email"),
            password=self.validated_data.get("password"),
            first_name=self.validated_data.get("first_name"),
            last_name=self.validated_data.get("last_name"),
        )


class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get('username')
        password = data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid username or password.")
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Both username and password are required.")

        data['user'] = user
        return data
```

here is postman snapshot.
[image: Postman request. there is no headers and authorization]

These are all I can show as code, if this propblem doesn't depend on my code, well, let me know, I don't know other possiblities that causes this error, but all configurations such as Google, postman, python and editor are perfect, like they are working well.

I am in production, so hope you guys can find proper solution for that.
Thanks from advance.

Yours, Abdusamad.

Comment: are you testing via Postman? if yes add your request snapshot

Comment: Are you using `SessionAuthentication` or `TokenAuthentication`?

Comment: in this project default authentication is session authentications just like provided in setings.py

Comment: but it is the same if I remove or change auth settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched and found an answer for that, that was a sily mistake, you should change sessionauthentication to tokenauthentication or other supported classes, in REST_FRAMEWORK variable in settings.py,
how silly situation it was, isnt it.

Comment: How the register API will work with any of the authentication system. How a user to be (not yet a user) will get a token? You should make the register API free of any auth or permission. Other API which needs user auth. can be done with Token Auth rather session auth which you have already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

an issue is in account.urls,
use

```
path("register/", views.RegisterAPIView().as_view(), name="register"),
path("login/", views.UserLoginView().as_view(), name="login"),
path("logout/", views.LogoutAPIView().as_view(), name="logout")
```

since RegisterAPIView(), UserLoginView(), LogoutAPIView() are classes

you can also try

```
class RegisterAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    model = User
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserCreationSerializer
    @staticmethod
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   ....
```

in account.views